# Getting "Cannot initialize organizational item" error while opening the Template Builder

Tags: template-builder

We are getting below error while opening our DEV environment in Template Builder, however working fine for production environment.

```
Cannot initialize organizational item: tcm:233-38287-2

<detail><Message><Line>Cannot initialize organizational item: tcm:233-38287-2</Line></Message><StackTrace><StackFrame method="GetList" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService" /></StackTrace></detail>

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.GetList(String locationId, GetListOptions listOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.OrganizationalItem.GetList(EnumItemType itemTypes, String[] basedOnSchemas, Boolean reload)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.UI.CompoundTemplateDesigner.DesignerForm.GetItemsList(IDialogItem DialogItem, Int64 itemTypes, String[] basedOnSchemas, Boolean reload)
```

Please suggest!!

Note: DEV environment while opening from browser is working fine.

Update:
After restarting the DEV server now we are getting this:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.StructureGroup'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{8D130EB3-CE17-4D29-9A7E-4828C95A2F7D}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
```

Comment: Are you running template builder with the same user as browsing the tridion. Also what is the version of your Tridion\Template Builder ?

Comment: YEs Saurabh....!!

Comment: version??? one more check: is the item "tcm:233-38287-2" there in tridion?

Comment: YEs Saurabh....!!

Comment: Manoj, do you get this error when you try opening an existing item from the "Recent Items" list or when you go to "File-> Open" ?

Comment: I'm guessing the work around was connecting with a different template builder or otherwise avoiding the "bad" TCM URI as I suspect Saurabh and Kunal were hinting at. Please post what worked and accept, Manoj. Thanks!